# How to display the name of the reference in my table AspNetUsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am wanting to display the name of the city which I have referenced in my table but I can not AspNetUser how.
This is the IndexViewModels:

```
 public class IndexViewModel {
    public bool HasPassword { get; set; }
    public IList<UserLoginInfo> Logins { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactor { get; set; }
    public bool BrowserRemembered { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Pais { get; set; }
    public int LocalidadID { get; set; }
    public string CodigoPostal { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public virtual Localidad Localidad { get; set; }
}
```

This is IdentityModels of class ApplicationUser.:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    public int LocalidadID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Pais { get; set; }        
    public string CodigoPostal { get; set; }        
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime  FechaRegistro { get; set; }

    // FOREIGN KEY
    public virtual Localidad Localidad { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager) {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

This is the controller Index

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
    {

        if (User.Identity.Name.Equals("guest@guest.com"))
            return RedirectToAction("GuestIndex");

        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var ctx = store.Context;
        var usuario = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var model = new IndexViewModel
        {
            HasPassword = HasPassword(),
            PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            Direccion = usuario.Direccion,
            Nombre = usuario.Nombre,
            Apellido = usuario.Apellido,
            Telefono = usuario.Telefono,
            LocalidadID = usuario.LocalidadID,
            //Localidades = db.Localidades.Where(l => l.LocalidadID==usuario.LocalidadID).Select(l => new {Nombre = l.Nombre}),
            CodigoPostal = usuario.CodigoPostal
        };            
        return View(model);
    }
```

And my View i throw me error:

```
<p>Argentina, @Model.Localidad.Departamento.Provincia.Nombre</p>
```

Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What is `Localidad `?

Comment: Localidad = city, Departamento = department, Provincia = State. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Solution was to add the following line:

```
Localidad = (from l in db.Localidades where l.LocalidadID == usuario.LocalidadID select l).First<Localidad>()
```

Leaving the function like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
{

    if (User.Identity.Name.Equals("guest@guest.com"))
        return RedirectToAction("GuestIndex");

    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
    var ctx = store.Context;
    var usuario = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    var model = new IndexViewModel
    {
        HasPassword = HasPassword(),
        PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
        TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
        Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
        BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
        Direccion = usuario.Direccion,
        Nombre = usuario.Nombre,
        Apellido = usuario.Apellido,
        Telefono = usuario.Telefono,
        LocalidadID = usuario.LocalidadID,
        Localidad = (from l in db.Localidades where l.LocalidadID == usuario.LocalidadID select l).First<Localidad>(),
        CodigoPostal = usuario.CodigoPostal
    };            
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Departamento.Provincia` of the `Localidad` won't be loaded, and maybe the `Localidad` itself.

You have to load it from the context by using `Include` or load it explicitly in another query
ex:

```
LocalidadID  = db.Localidads.Include("Departamento.Provincia.").Where(a=>a.LocalidadId == usuario .LocalidadID)
```

Comment: thanks but throws me the following error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<PedidosOnline.Models.Localidad>' to 'int'

Comment: Thank you very much! I shepherded, I've used this way as I looked conversion error, and instead of assigning the FOREIGN KEY "LocalidadID" is assigned to the LOCALITY the model.

Localidad = (from l in db.Localidades where l.LocalidadID == usuario.LocalidadID select l).First<Localidad>(),